# Get Bitcoin price hourly or minute using Coinbase API in python

Tags: python, bitcoin, coinbase-api

I am trying to make a program that gets daily price of bitcoin in specific date.

For example:

If I want to get 2017-01-01's bitcoin price. I should be able to do

```
client.get_historic_prices(data = "2017-01-01")
```

I am able to run python `print(client.get_historic_prices())` But this shows me too many daily Bitcoin prices.

Is there way to get specific date's bitcoin price using Coinbase API?
Also, can I specify duration like from `2017-01-01` to `2017-03-01`?

Answer (score -2):

check this out if it can help you:

> https://github.com/CoinCapDev/CoinCap.io